# Finding max occurence of element, array syntax

Tags: c, algorithm, search

The following code is an algorithm for searching for the maximum occurrence of an element in an array. This solution assumes that an element ranges from 0 to n-1.

```
void MaxRepetitions( int A[], int n ) {

int i=0; max=0, maxIndex;

for(i=0, i<n, i++) 
    A[A[i]%n] +=n;

for( i=0, i<n, i++)

    if (A[i]/n > max) { 
       max = A[i]/n;
       maxIndex=i;

}

return maxIndex;
}
```

How is `A[A[i]%n] +=n;` expanded?

Is `A[A[i]%n] = A[A[i]%n] + n` correct?

--

### Edit

For the example where A = [2, 4, 7, 5, 4, 11], where n=6

```
A[0]%n = 2
A[1]%n = 4
A[2]%n = 1
A[3]%n = 5
A[4]%n = 4
A[5]%n = 5
```

After this loop:

```
for(i=0, i<n, i++) 
    A[A[i]%n] = A[A[i]%n] + n;

Iteration 1: 

A[A[0]%n] = A[A[0]%n] + 6   --> A[2] = A[2] + 6  --> A[2] = 13

The array is now: A = [2, 4, 13, 5, 4, 11]

Iteration 2:

A[A[1]%n] = A[A[1]%n] + 6   --> A[4] = A[4] + 6  --> A[4] = 10

The array is now: A = [2, 4, 13, 5, 10, 11]


Iteration 3:

A[A[2]%n] = A[A[2]%n] + 6   --> A[1] = A[1] + 6  --> A[1] = 10

The array is now: A = [2, 10, 13, 5, 10, 11]

Iteration 4:

A[A[3]%n] = A[A[3]%n] + 6   --> A[5] = A[5] + 6  --> A[5] = 17

The array is now: A = [2, 10, 13, 5, 10, 17]

Iteration 5:

A[4] now is 10

A[A[4]%n] = A[A[4]%n] + 6   --> A[4] = A[4] + 6  --> A[4] = 16

The array is now: A = [2, 10, 13, 5, 16, 17]

Iteration 6:

A[5] now is 17

A[A[5]%n] = A[A[5]%n] + 6   --> A[5] = A[5] + 6  --> A[5] = 23
```

The array is now: A = [2, 10, 13, 5, 16, 23]

Now, once the second loop runs, A[i]/n for each of the elements is: A [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 ]

It looks like this algorithm will choose 11 as the element with most occurrences which isn't true. Any help?

Comment: `How is A[A[i]%n] +=n; expanded?`? yes it's `A[A[i]%n]  = A[A[i]%n] + n;`.

Comment: ok i now have a follow up question pending

Comment: Don't you mean that an element ranges from 0 to n-1 (not n to n-1)? This code won't work properly if any elements are negative or greater than n-1.

Comment: at least `maxIndex = i` !

Comment: So your question is how the `+=` operator works? Please cook down your question to a minimal example, please, and format it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have said, `<anything> += <value>` is equivalent to `<anything> = <anything> + <value>` except that `<anything>` is evaluated only once.

Your analysis of the running of the algorithm is correct, but the problem is that the input violates the stated constraint that all elements are between 0 and n-1. In effect, since 11 % 6 = 5, the answer produced by the algorithm isn't completely wrong (modulo 6, the value 5 occurs the same number of times as the value 4). However, there is a further problem in that because the input constraint is violated, the counts are off for reasons that I explain in a comment below.

The best way to understand how this works is to look at another algorithm which, while seemingly quite different, is actually the same thing. This other algorithm is:

1. Allocate a separate array `C[n]`. (`C` for "count".)
2. Loop through each element `A[i]` of `A` and set `C[A[i]] += 1`. It's not too hard to see that, since each `A[i]` is between 0 and `n-1`, when this step finishes, `C[j]` for any `j` will be the number of times that the value `j` occurs among all the `A[i]`.
3. Thus, the *position* of the largest element of `C` is the most frequently occurring value in `A` (with ties being resolved arbitrarily). Simply loop through `C` to find where this occurs and return the result.

Now the algorithm you posted is exactly that, but cleverly making use of two facts, both of which rely on the original values of `A[i]` being between `0` and `n-1`:

1. The value of `A[i]%n` will be exactly equal to the *original* value of `A[i]` regardless of how many times `n` has been added to `A[i]`.
2. The value of `A[i]/n` will be exactly equal to the number of times `n` has been added to `A[i]`, regardless of the original value of `A[i]`.

So if we modify the second algorithm by adding `n` instead of 1, and by using `%n` and `/n` as is done in your posted algorithm, we can make `A` serve for both holding the original values and for holding the counts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Two points:
1. I believe I have the last iteration correct, it's just under the code block.
2. The function returns 5, but if you look at the original array, A[], the number 5 only occurs once, where the number 4 occurs twice.

Comment: @martinap - Sorry, I should have noticed and commented on this earlier. Your original array violates the input constraint that the elements are all between 0 and n-1. Specifically `A[2]` is 7 and `A[5]` is 11. In effect, it is like initializing the `C` array to all zeroes except for a count of 1 at indexes 2 and 5. Then, 5 gets incremented twice: once for `A[3]` and again for `A[5]`. Also note that the count of 2 is one too high because `A[2] > 5` and the count of 1 is one too high because `A[2]` is counted as another occurrence of 1.

Comment: @martinap - I updated my answer to address this.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
A[A[i]%n] +=n
```

Is expanded to be equivalent to this:

```
A[A[i]%n] = A[A[i]%n] + n
```

**Except** that side-effects are only evaluated once. In other words, if the left expression had employed operators with side-effects like `++` and `--`, then these side-effects would only occur once, contrary to what had happened if you had actually written out the whole `x = x + y` expression, where side-effects in `x` would be evaluated twice.

Answer (score 0):

A[A[i]%n] +=n

```
A[i]           : value contained in array A at position i
A[i]%n         : remainder of dividing this value by n (used to not allow this index go beyond the size of A
A[A[i]%n]      : the value contained in that new position
A[A[i]%n] += n : add n to this value
```

**Numerical example** :

```
A[3] = {7, 10, 24}
n = 3

i = 0
A[A[0]%3] = A[7%3] // 7 = 2*3 + 1
          = A[1]
          = 10
add 3 ==> A[1] = 13

i = 1
A[A[1]%3] = A[13%3] // 13 = 4*3 +1
          = A[1]
          = 13
add 3 ==> A[1] = 16

i = 2
A[A[2]%3] = A[24%3] // 24 = 8*3 + 0
          = A[1]
          = 7
add 3 ==> A[1] = 10
```